# mule move file to another location dynamically from the db query

Tags: mule, mule-el

I want to move files to location D:\target dynamically  from the query `select filepath from emp where status='y'`:

This is my table:

```
emp_Name    File Path      File Name    Status
ABC         D:\emp           abc.txt     y
xyz         D:\emp           xyz.txt     y
bcs         D:\emp           bcs.txt     n
```

Following is my source code :

```
<flow name="testdbFlow1">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
        path="/" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint queryKey="allEmps"
        queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="JDBCConnector" exchange-pattern="request-response"
        doc:name="Database" />

    <foreach doc:name="Foreach">
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[payload.status == 'Y']">
                <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
                    <set-variable variableName="filePath" value="#[payload.filepath]"
                        doc:name="Variable" />
                    <set-variable variableName="filename" value="#[payload.filename]"
                        doc:name="Variable" />

                    <logger message="#[filePath]" level="INFO"
                        doc:name="Logger" />
                    <logger message="#[filename]"
                        level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

                    <file:inbound-endpoint path="#[filePath]" name="input" doc:name="File" 
                        pollingFrequency="12000" responseTimeout="10000"> <file:filename-wildcard-filter 
                        pattern="#[filename]" /> </file:inbound-endpoint>

                    <file:outbound-endpoint name="output" path="D:\target" doc:name="File"/>

                </processor-chain>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
                    <set-variable variableName="filePath" value="#[payload.filepath]"
                        doc:name="Variable" />
                    <set-variable variableName="filename" value="#[payload.filename]"
                        doc:name="Variable" />

                    <logger message="#[filePath]" level="INFO"
                        doc:name="Logger" />
                    <logger message="#[filename]"
                        level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

                </processor-chain>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </foreach>

</flow>
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the logs? Because I don't believe it's valid to have an inbound endpoint in the middle of the processor chain. Also, are you certain that the file name and path can be accessed in such a way? Are you certain the payload has them? I would add a a logger right after entering the foreach to see what the payload is.

Answer (score 0):

Inbound doesn't work out of the box in the middle of the flow. I would suggest a simpler solution using Groovy because you know exactly the file you need to consume.

Instead of using file:inbound create a input stream manually:

```
<set-payload value="#[groovy: new java.io.FileInputStream(new java.io.File(filename))]"/>
```

You will have to delete the file with another groovy script after consumed.

Comment: Thanks Peter for replying me. After consuming file using Groovy how can i move to D:\target folder. Please suggest me

Comment: The Groovy script is not consuming the file, but instead returns a InputStream (as the file:inbound-endpoint would have). You can leave your file:outbound-endpoint as is to copy the file content there. But After your file:outbound-endpoint you have to delete the source file manually with a script, for example <set-variable variableName="removed" value="#[groovy: new java.io.File(filename).delete()]"/>