# mule move multiple files from one folder to other inside for each loop

Tags: mule

```
Below is my mule flow. I want to move my corresponding from the jdbc query rseult set

----------------------------------------------------


<foreach doc:name="Foreach"  counterVariableName="#[message.payload.size()]">
      <logger message="#[payload.filepath]  -  #[payload.name] - #[payload.filename]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    </foreach>

---------------------------------------------------------------------

 <jdbc-ee:postgresql-data-source name="PostgreSQL_Data_Source"
                  user="postgres" password="postgres" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
                  transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="PostgreSQL Data Source">
    </jdbc-ee:postgresql-data-source>
      <jdbc-ee:connector name="JDBCConnector"
                  dataSource-ref="PostgreSQL_Data_Source" validateConnections="true"
                  doc:name="JDBCConnector">
        <jdbc-ee:query key="emprec" value="select  * from emp where salary>50000";">
      </jdbc-ee:query>
    </jdbc-ee:connector>
      <flow name="empflow" >
        <quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000"
                         doc:name="Quartz" jobName="CronJobSchedule" repeatInterval="0"
                         cronExpression="0 0/1 * ? * MON-FRI" repeatCount="1">
          <quartz:event-generator-job>
            <quartz:payload>quartzSchedular started</quartz:payload>
          </quartz:event-generator-job>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
        <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint queryKey="emprec"
                         queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="JDBCConnector" exchange-pattern="request-response"
                         doc:name="Database" />
        <logger message="Size of payload is ::: #[message.payload.size()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <foreach doc:name="Foreach"  counterVariableName="#[message.payload.size()]">
          <logger message="#[payload.filepath]  -  #[payload.name] - #[payload.filename]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        </foreach>
      </flow>
```

please suggest way to move whatever filename  got using query result ,that file need to move other location
Inside for each loop i tried file inbound and outpoint .but it is not worked out

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372873/mule-move-file-to-another-location-dynamically-from-the-db-query/29383972#29383972

Answer (score 0):

1 - You need to load the file, for that I suggest using the [Mule Requester Module](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester/blob/master/README.md). You can find more on it in this [blogpost](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/introducing-the-mule-requester-module/).

2 - Right after that you can move it using a file outbound endpoint.

Here's an example:

```
<mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="file:///Users/anafelisatti/test.txt" returnClass="java.lang.String" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
<file:outbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" outputPattern="test.txt" path="/Users/anafelisatti/Documents"/>
```

Hope that helps.